# how to focus search textbox based on selection of another dropdown option - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my application, i have to filter the products based on name and category name. There are one search text box and one dropdown select box. In dropdown select box, there are two options
**1. Search products by name 2. Search products by category name**. Based on the selected option, the search textbox will enable and focused.

**template code**

```
<el-form>
      <el-row :gutter="15"
              type="flex"
              class="search__product">
        <el-col class="filter_option">
            <app-select name="ProductFilter"
                        :options="filterOptions"
                        :selected="selectedSearchOption"
                        @onChange="onSearchOptionChange" />
        </el-col><el-col class="search_input">
            <el-input placeholder="Search product"
                      aria-label="Search product"
                      @keyup.enter.native="searchProduct"
                      v-model="filterText">
            </el-input>
        </el-col>
      </el-row>
    </el-form>
```

**Method to display the dropdown values**

```
    get filterOptions(): OptionTypes[] {
    return [
      { label: 'Search by Product Name', value: 'Product' },
      { label: 'Search by Category Name', value: 'Category' }
    ]
  }
```

**Search input for product**

```
searchProduct() {
    if (this.filterText !== '') {
      this.$store.dispatch('fetchProductsBySearchName', this.filterText)
    }
  }
```

**Option Change event for dropdown**

```
    onSearchOptionChange(value) {
    this.selectedSearchOption = value
  }
```

this is working fine for searching products by name. Now, i want to implement it based on dropdown selection to enable the search textbox and focus it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note answer is kinda specific to library `Element-ui`'s `el-input`:

You Select will remains same:

```
<app-select name="ProductFilter"
            :options="filterOptions"
            :selected="selectedSearchOption"
            @onChange="onSearchOptionChange" />
```

User Ref for el-input:

```
<el-input ref="myInput"
          placeholder="Search product"
          @keyup.enter.native="searchProduct"
          v-model="filterText">
```

In your Method:

```
onSearchOptionChange(value) {
  this.selectedSearchOption = value

  // In multiple ways you can get this done (selecting `input` element)
  // use any one line mentioned below ;)
  this.$refs.myInput.$el.firstElementChild.focus();
  this.$refs.myInput.$el.lastElementChild.focus();
  this.$refs.myInput.$el.children[0].focus();

  this.$refs.myInput.$el.querySelector('input').focus(); // my favourite, future proof 
}
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned by @charlie, you may need to move code into `this.$nextTick`:

```
onSearchOptionChange(value) {
  this.selectedSearchOption = value

  this.$nextTick(() => { 
    // In multiple ways you can get this done (selecting `input` element)
    // use any one line mentioned below ;)
    this.$refs.myInput.$el.firstElementChild.focus();
    this.$refs.myInput.$el.lastElementChild.focus();
    this.$refs.myInput.$el.children[0].focus();

    this.$refs.myInput.$el.querySelector('input').focus(); // my favourite, future proof 
  })
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this might not work since you will need to hear for the `nextTick`. Something like `this.$nextTick(() => { /**  focus input here */ })`